# ::before and ::after content always above and beneath <p> content?

Tags: html, css, less

For a project I need to get the Font Awesome quote icons right before and after the `<p>` content. Right now it displays itself above and beneath it at all times.

Here is the HTML:

```
<blockqoute>
<p><strong>Text</strong></p>
</blockqoute>
```

And the CSS I'm using:

```
blockquote {
  border: none;
  &:before {
    .fa();
      content: @fa-var-quote-left;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  &:after {
    .fa();
    content: @fa-var-quote-right;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image: And this is what I'm currently getting.]

The qoute icons need to start right in front of the text, and right after too.

I'm using the CMS Typo3.

Comment: Can you please add css block instead of sass block code...

Comment: try to add `display: inline-block` property to `<p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to the paragraph element, and remove the `float` from the after pseudo-element – because `p` is a block level element, they will be on their own, new lines if you apply the pseudo-elements to the containing block.

```
blockquote p {
  &::before {
    .fa();
    content: @fa-var-quote-left;
  }

  &::after {
    .fa();
    content: @fa-var-quote-right;
  }
}
```

The `position` and `display` properties are probably not needed, it depends on what other styles you will apply.

Answer (score 3):

you need all your elements on the same block level.
while your `:before` is `inline-block` the following ´p´ is by default `block`, so every inline-element before or after are separated by newlines.

I assume you need to set

```
blockquote p { display: inline-block; }
```